# How to achieve this layout using apache tiles 2?

Tags: html, tiles, apache-tiles, tiles2

[image]

Having problems creating such a layout. Controllers trigger dash content, and the layout should be created. Now I have this definitions, and I am blocked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="masterLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/master.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="headerInclude" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footerInclude" value="" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="dashboardLayout" extends="masterLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body"  value="dashboardLayoutBody" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="dashboardLayoutBody" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/dashboard.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/parts/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body"/>
    </definition>

    <!-- this page is triggered -->
    <definition name="login_page" extends="masterLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/login.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <!-- this page is triggered -->    
    <definition name="some_page" extends="dashboardLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/content/admin_groups/supervisor.jsp"/>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

master layout has this content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Master css, js, meta, tags additions .... -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="headerInclude"/>
</head>
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>

    <!-- Master css, js, meta, tags additions .... -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footerInclude"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I need somehow to extend template and also have own template, to include menu there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a new comer to jsp templating, I didn't realized that I can use `jsp:include` in parallel with *Aapache Tiles*, which solved the problem.

The main problem was that I couldn't include the menu once only in the dashboard layout, and be used everywhere.

Using only tiles, there is `cascade` attribute on a `put-attribute` tag that allow that to be used in other attributes also.

Keep in mind that `cascade` needs `DOCTYPE tiles-definition` minimum version 2.1

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
```